# Automate Arnold "Ass Export" options in python for Maya

Tags: python, maya

Regarding batch exporting Arnold .ass files using python. I have already written a tool which batch exports selected objects in Maya to separate .ass files using predefined options. This works great.

Now what I want is to give the user checkboxes in the UI to select the options of Arnold export (the same which are there in Maya ass export options - lights, cameras, shapes, shaders etc)

Something like this:

[image]

The thing is: the current command takes a string for options.

```
pmc.exportSelected(export_file, f=1, typ="ASS Export",
    options="-mask 8;-lightLinks 0;-compressed;-boundingBox;-shadowLinks 0")
```

And the "mask" int changes based on options selected. Can anyone help me.

note: pmc is pymel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently facing the same problem. The best i've got so far is to make a dictionary with the combinations I need. I only need a couple so this is doable, but it is not an approach i would take if I needed as many as it sounds like you do

```
mask = {'camera': 2, 'camera_drivers': 200 }
```

and such.

If you're giving all these options to the artists, why not let them do it with the arnold button, it's already been made

Comment: Thanks! I'm not working on the tool anymore, but if I get back to it anytime, I'll try this.